# code::blocks smart sense / autocomplection not working with namespaces

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codeblocks

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot see any hints when calling object constructor. The weird thing is that I don't see it when I'm not using "using namespace ke;" (my namespace), but when I use it everything is fine. This error only affects constructors. I'm using Code::Blocks 17.12

Not working:

```
//includes

int main()
{
    ke::Circle circle_test(/*arguments*/); // no arguments hints
    circle_test.setPosition(69, 420); // works fine

    // the rest of the code
}
```

Everything is fine:

```
//includes

using namespace ke;

int main()
{
    Circle circle_test(/*arguments*/);
    circle_test.setPosition(69, 420); // works fine too

    // the rest of the code
}
```

Is this because I'm using old code blocks version or I added my files recursively? Or maybe something with constructor declaration?

EDIT
includes:

```
#include "KEngine/Graphics.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <cmath>
```

KEngine Graphics includes ke::Circle

```
#include "Objects/Circle.hpp"
```

Comment: Could you please add includes? It helps to reproduce the error. It seems that problem with other code

Comment: @mascai OK, if you need more code I can add link to the whole project. Btw can multiple constructors (with one without arguments) be the problem?